# How to put and get values from this dictionary I implemented

Tags: dictionary, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

so after a bunch of trial and error, I'm pretty sure this is what it's supposed to be.

```
type ('a,'b) dict3 = ('a -> 'b option)

let empty3 : unit -> ('a,'b) dict3 =  fun x -> (fun y ->  None);;

let put3 : 'a -> 'b -> ('a,'b) dict3 -> ('a,'b) dict3 = fun key value dict -> fun x -> if x = key then Some value else dict x;;

let get3 : 'a -> ('a,'b) dict3 -> 'b option = fun key dict -> dict key;;
```

But now that I have this, I'm very confused how they communicate with one another. I tried doing a test for get3, and I came up with:

```
let _ = assert (get3 42 (fun lst -> Some (String.length "charizard")) = Some 9);;
```

which I think is correct. But I don't know how to write an assert case for put3, as I don't know how to show the ('a, 'b) dict3, nor how to get empty3 to return None.

Comment: What do you mean by "show"? Printing? Functions are not printable therefore it is impossible to print your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I want to have it as a comment, but I need 50 reputation for that, so I try to write a little bit more.

`put3` gives a new function, which cannot be compared if I remember correctly. I do not think there is anything to assert.

Perhaps try putting something and then retrieve it using `get3` and assert the values are the same?

Getting empty3 to return None is the easiest.
You assert you get `None` from `empty3()`

```
assert (get3 "foo" (empty3 ()) = None);;
```

BTW I think `empty3` should be written as `fun () -> fun _ -> None` if you want to keep the type signature.

Or simply `fun _ ->  None`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `empty3` is supposed to be an empty dictionary, not a function that creates an empty dictionary, so you probably want

```
let empty3 : ('a,'b) dict3 =  fun _ ->  None;;
```

Your test case for `get3` isn't very useful, as the dictionary that returns 9 for every key isn't one you can construct using `empty3` and `put3`, so you're not giving `get3` a valid dictionary.
This means that the test provides no information.

What you should test is that your functions implement a dictionary with specific properties, not that the dictionary has a specific structure.
(Your tests should work regardless of the representation of an `('a,'b) dict3`.)

You have three cases that you need to test:

- If `d` is the empty dictionary, `get3 k d` is `None`.
- If `d` isn't the empty dictionary, but doesn't contain a value for `k`, `get3 k d` is `None`.
- If `d` isn't the empty dictionary, and contains the value `v` for `k`, `get3 k d` is `Some v`.

These would provide useful information:

```
let _ = assert (get3 43 empty3 = None);;
let _ = assert (get3 43 (put3 44 9 empty3) = None);;
let _ = assert (get3 43 (put3 43 9 empty3) = Some 9);;
```